# File not found with Google Calendar API

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am having trouble doing the *quickstart.php* using the Composer dependency manager.

I have used Composer in order to require the Google Calendar API. *autoload.php* is present in the vendor folder. And I am just running the code from this page: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php

The error I am getting is

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Service_Calendar'

on *quickstart.php* line 12.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

I've tried using: `composer dump-autoload` which has done nothing to remedy this.

Thanks!

Comment: your error message seems incomplete. Beside that, I just installed the component with `composer` and tried `quickstart.php`, I do not get any error at line 12. Are you sure you have run `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0` and the commande succeeded ?

Comment: @Daishi My apologies, the full error message is "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Service_Calendar' not found in" and then the path that I am working out of. I am sure that I have ran the composer command to install the API client, and I have confirmed that the vendor folder is in the same directory.

Comment: @Arron try deleting your `vendor` directrory and reinstalling with `composer install`. Check also that the value `__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'` is actually correct.

Comment: Did you check that you physically have the file it self?
vendor\google\apiclient-services\src\Google\Service\Calendar.php
It's the file defining Google_Service_Calendar class